# Inner product of De Rham cohomology classes

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, hodge-theory

Is there a well-defined inner product between cohomology classes?
In particular, is it possible to extend the Hodge inner product?
If I try, I obtain this:

$$\int *(\omega + d\lambda)\wedge (\sigma + d\mu) = 
\int (*\omega\wedge\sigma + *d\lambda\wedge\sigma + *\omega\wedge d\mu + *d\lambda\wedge d\mu)$$

Is it possible to discard the last terms as an exact form, or to define anyway a product that does something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible because the integration depends heavily on the representative you choose.

Here's an illustration: take a circle $S^1$ and a bump form $b_1$ around $1$ (I am thinking of the circle realized as unit complex numbers). This generates $H^1(S^1)$. Similarly, $b_{-1}$ around $-1$ is another generator of the same class. You would expect the inner product of these two forms be non-trivial. But dualizing and taking products will leave you with zero form that integrates to zero.

Comment: This is such a good picture! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're working on a compact Riemannian manifold, each cohomology class is represented by a unique harmonic form, so use the harmonic forms.

Comment: This kind of misses the point. Of course you can endow every finite dimensional vector space with inner product. But OP asked for one that works for classes, not just randomly picked representatives.

Comment: @Marek: *You* are missing the point. This is far from a random choice. Given the Riemannian structure (which we need for all this discussion), it is canonical.

Comment: I am well aware of the role of harmonic forms in Hodge theory, thank you. I am just saying that you answered a different question than OP asked..

Comment: ..which, as far as I can see, asked whether the inner product on all forms descends to cohomology. The answer is it doesn't.

Comment: We're interpreting his question differently. I read it as "Is it possible to ...?" I've given a canonical way to say yes, and you've given the obvious way to say no.

Comment: Your answer is canonical, but it is also useless. Your inner product doesn't give any non-trivial information because the harmonic classes can be continuously deformed without changing the cohomology.

Comment: Wrong. As I said, there is a *unique* harmonic form (the element of least norm) in each class. What *is* your problem?

Comment: (+1) I was originally somewhat confused by this answer, given that the wedge product of harmonic forms need not be harmonic, but it looks like the operation of taking the harmonic part of the wedge product of harmonic forms is something that has been considered in the literature (see, e.g., http://mathoverflow.net/a/4543) So, the Hodge inner product doesn't naïvely descend to de Rham cohomology, but I guess there is a canonical fix in terms of harmonic forms?

Comment: My problem with this answer is that IMO it has nothing to do with OP. While I agree that it is useful to consider harmonic forms in many cases to prove various theorems about cohomology, in this particular case it's completely irrelevant. You cannot use your product in any topological application (I'll be happy if you prove me wrong), since it is not functorial. That's it. Note that I didn't downvote, I am just trying to explain to you my point of view. If you don't care about that then we can agree to disagree. Cheers, no harm intended.

Comment: Yup, I had considered taking the harmonic representative. That works indeed, and the choice is canonical on a Riemannian manifold. 
What I was looking for though was something invariant in the class! Apparently, there is no such thing. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

No. If $\omega = \sigma = 0$ and $\lambda = \eta$ is smooth, then
$$
 \int_M \ast (\omega+d\lambda) \wedge (\sigma+d\eta) - \int_M \ast \omega \wedge \sigma = \int_M \ast d\lambda \wedge d\lambda = \|d\lambda\|^2,
$$
which vanishes if and only if $d\lambda = 0$.