# Hodge inner product of the compact support de Rham cohomologies

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Let us consider de Rham chain complex $\Omega^{*}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with compact support. There is a well-defined inner product on such a complex - the Hodge inner product, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}*\alpha\wedge\beta,
\end{equation}
where $\alpha,\beta \in \Omega^{*}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. We know that de Rham cohomologies of such a complex is a subspace of $\Omega^{*}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and given by
\begin{equation}
  H^{*}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)=\begin{cases}
    \mathbb{R}, & \text{in dimension n}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Naively, it seems that I can restrict the above inner product to a subspace - that is, to a cohomologies and get well-defined pairing between two elements of $H^{*}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or at least on some chosen representatives. But there are just top-forms in $H^{*}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and all pairings are zero. So, the inner product is degenerate.

I can't figure out where my logic breaks. Why does this happen?

Because as I know there exists an inner product between representatives on de Rham cohomologies of non-compact support forms, see e.g. [Inner product of De Rham cohomology classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448717/inner-product-of-de-rham-cohomology-classes).

Comment: Why do you think that the induced inner product is degenerate on $H^n_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić For example: if I take two representatives of cohomologies, there are only the forms of maximal rank in it. So, if I will pair two n-forms, the inner product gives me zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: careful: the Hodge star takes $k$ -forms to $(n-k)$ forms!

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić but the space of $(n-k)$ is empty in cohomologies